# PHP: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php

This is a common error, I'm sure, but I can't figure out why I'm getting it. I'm new to OOP, but I figure I'm instantiating the object incorrectly?

First the include:

```
<?php include("/classes/justgiving.php"); ?>
```

Which is absolutely correct, as far I can tell.

Then I try to instantiate...

```
$justgiving = new JustGiving();
```

And then when I try to run the method in the object:

```
$justgiving->createAccount($xml);
```

And in the class .php file:

```
class JustGiving{

  function createAccount($xml) {

  // function code

  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function createAccount() on a non-object`

I have a feeling this is a real newb error, and it's something really obvious.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please check whether include path is correct?

Comment: I hope you have your class inside of php (<?php and ?>) tags. Otherwise it's just text and therefore php hasn't defined your class.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine (proof: http://ideone.com/LMkkl ). Please post your entire code.

Comment: Yes, good point. It turns out I was making the silly mistake of instantiating the object from outside of the function where I was calling it. `*facepalm*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. what you have written seems like it should work.  Maybe your problem is elsewhere?

The only reason I can think of for getting this error would be that you're trying to call a method before initializing the object, e.g.

```
$justgiving->createAccount($xml);
$justgiving = new JustGiving();
```

Comment: Yes, that crossed my mind, too. But it's not the case :( I'll re-look at the code for any other obvious mistakes.